# How to insert some "lines" from another script into the main script

Tags: python, import, refactoring

Suppose I have this script:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
p = figure()
p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
p.title.text = "Title"
p.title.text_color = "Orange"
p.title.text_font = "times"
show(p)
output_file("file.html")
```

I want to reuse lines 4 through 6 in other scripts without having to copy and paste them in every script.

If I put lines 4 - 6 in a separate .py file and then import that file into the main script, there will be a NameError about the undefined 'p' object.

What's the proper way to reuse such lines?

Answer (score 2):

Use a function

```
# in settitle.py
def set_title(p):
    p.title.text = "Title"
    p.title.text_color = "Orange"
    p.title.text_font = "times"
```

and import the function like so

```
from settitle import set_title
```

and use

```
from settitle import set_title
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
p = figure()
p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
set_title(p)
show(p)
output_file("file.html")
```